# Python Caesar cypher

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a dict that can apply a Caesar Cypher to a letter.
I need it to be in one dict for upper and lower but cannot figure put how to get both into one dict.

```
import string

def Coder(shift):

    alpha = string.ascii_lowercase
    ALPHA = string.ascii_uppercase
    if shift in range(0,26):

        return dict(zip(ALPHA, ALPHA[shift:] + ALPHA[0:shift])), dict(zip(alpha, alpha[shift:] + alpha[0:shift]))
```

Comment: I wasn't able to do it in a dict. I did it the *inefficient* way - writing out a massive `if`/`else` program! Can't wait for the answer.

Comment: well the alternative would be the same for me, would be nice to avoid that for a change :)

Comment: Did you know there is a [built-in encoder](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) for the ceasar cypher; `'This is a test.'.encode('rot13')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import string

def Coder(shift):
    alpha = string.ascii_lowercase
    ALPHA = string.ascii_uppercase
    if 0 <= shift < 26:
        unshifted_letters = ALPHA + alpha
        shifted_letters = ALPHA[shift:] + ALPHA[:shift] + alpha[shift:] + alpha[:shift]
        return dict(zip(unshifted_letters, shifted_letters))
```

But as others have said, better solutions are [`encode('rot13')`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) and [`string.maketrans`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans). In particular, this: "rot_13  rot13   Unicode string  Returns the Caesar-cypher encryption of the operand".

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to programming, avoid trying to "do everything on one line".

string.index( substring ) finds the position of substring in string.

a % b takes the remainder of a divided by b.

string.upper() returns an uppercased version of string.

Knowing this, you should be able to understand every line in this program:

```
import string
translation = {}
shift = 5
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
for letter in alphabet:
    position = alphabet.index( letter )
    new_position = (position + shift) % len( alphabet )
    translation[ letter ] = alphabet[ new_position ]
    translation[ letter.upper() ] = alphabet[ new_position ].upper()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.update()`:

First create a dictionary of uppercase letters and then update that dict with a dictionary of lowercase letters:

```
In [8]: from string import *

In [9]: al=ascii_lowercase

In [10]: au=ascii_uppercase

In [11]: for shift in range(2):
    dic1=dict(zip(au, au[shift:] + au[0:shift]))
    dic1.update(dict(zip(al, al[shift:] + al[0:shift])))
    print dic1
   ....:     
{'A': 'A', 'C': 'C', 'B': 'B', 'E': 'E', 'D': 'D', 'G': 'G', 'F': 'F', 'I': 'I', 'H': 'H', 'K': 'K', 'J': 'J', 'M': 'M', 'L': 'L', 'O': 'O', 'N': 'N', 'Q': 'Q', 'P': 'P', 'S': 'S', 'R': 'R', 'U': 'U', 'T': 'T', 'W': 'W', 'V': 'V', 'Y': 'Y', 'X': 'X', 'Z': 'Z', 'a': 'a', 'c': 'c', 'b': 'b', 'e': 'e', 'd': 'd', 'g': 'g', 'f': 'f', 'i': 'i', 'h': 'h', 'k': 'k', 'j': 'j', 'm': 'm', 'l': 'l', 'o': 'o', 'n': 'n', 'q': 'q', 'p': 'p', 's': 's', 'r': 'r', 'u': 'u', 't': 't', 'w': 'w', 'v': 'v', 'y': 'y', 'x': 'x', 'z': 'z'}
{'A': 'B', 'C': 'D', 'B': 'C', 'E': 'F', 'D': 'E', 'G': 'H', 'F': 'G', 'I': 'J', 'H': 'I', 'K': 'L', 'J': 'K', 'M': 'N', 'L': 'M', 'O': 'P', 'N': 'O', 'Q': 'R', 'P': 'Q', 'S': 'T', 'R': 'S', 'U': 'V', 'T': 'U', 'W': 'X', 'V': 'W', 'Y': 'Z', 'X': 'Y', 'Z': 'A', 'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'b': 'c', 'e': 'f', 'd': 'e', 'g': 'h', 'f': 'g', 'i': 'j', 'h': 'i', 'k': 'l', 'j': 'k', 'm': 'n', 'l': 'm', 'o': 'p', 'n': 'o', 'q': 'r', 'p': 'q', 's': 't', 'r': 's', 'u': 'v', 't': 'u', 'w': 'x', 'v': 'w', 'y': 'z', 'x': 'y', 'z': 'a'}
```

or you can also use `str.translate()` with `string.maketrans`:

```
for shift in xrange(4):
    t=maketrans(au+al,au[shift:]+au[:shift]+al[shift:]+al[:shift])
    print "abcxyzABCXYZ".translate(t)
   ....:     
abcxyzABCXYZ
bcdyzaBCDYZA
cdezabCDEZAB
defabcDEFABC
```

> S.translate(table [,deletechars]) -> string
>
> Return a copy of the string S, where all characters occurring in the
>   optional argument deletechars are removed, and the remaining
>   characters have been mapped through the given translation table, which
>   must be a string of length 256 or None. If the table argument is None,
>   no translation is applied and the operation simply removes the
>   characters in deletechars.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham My code includes shift=0, you must be running it incorrectly. (`range(2)` means `(0,1)`)